# BungeeCord not reachable after enabling ServerSocket

Tags: java, sockets, plugins, minecraft, bungeecord

I'm working on an web based API for a BungeeCord Server but after opening the ServerSocket on Port 8082 the BungeeCord on Port 25565 isn't available furthermore.

This class is opening the ServerSocket:

```
package de.pardrox.bungeeapi;
import java.io.BufferedReader;

import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class HTTP {
    static router router = new router();
  public static void main(int args) {
    try {
            int port = args;
      @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    ServerSocket apiweb = new ServerSocket(port);
      for (;;) {
        Socket client = apiweb.accept();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream());

        out.print("HTTP/1.1 200 \r\n");
        out.print("Content-Type: text/plain\r\n");
        out.print("Connection: close\r\n");
        out.print("\r\n");

        String line;
        InetAddress ip_client = client.getInetAddress();
        main.syslog("Request of client "+ip_client.toString());
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
          if (line.length() == 0)
            break;
            if(line.toLowerCase().contains("GET".toLowerCase()))
            {
                String url = line.replace("GET ", "").replace(" HTTP/1.1", "");
                out.print(router.get(url));
            }
        }
        out.close();
        in.close();
        client.close();
      }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
      System.err.println(e);
      System.err.println("Call HTTP(<port>)");
    }
  }
}
```

Does anyone have an idea why opening the ServerSocket seems to close the Socket of the Gameserver? Eclipse doesn't find any error and the gameserver itself seems to run fine. The API is reachable also without any trouble.

For completeness:
I've startet the socket class with HTTP.main(8082);

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a mistake at `for (;;)`.
This will create an infinite loop that will run for ever....
Maybe this will cause the Main Thread of BungeeCord server to stop responding.
Try removing the `for (;;)` and using this code below instead of just running the code in the Default BungeeCord Thread. Since BungeeCord doesn't allows you to create custom Threads, the only way to do this is using the Scheduler and running a Runnable asynchronous.

```
ProxyServer.getInstance().getScheduler().runAsync(yourPluginHere, new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Put your code here
    }
});
```